# Regex which validate specific positive number values only

Tags: javascript, regex, string, validation, number-formatting

I want to validate numbers in an input in Javascript.

The input should accept:

```
empty input ''
positive number '123'
decimal number '23.89' '23.88888' '.89'
```

But it shouldn't accept negative numbers  and also '0.-99'
I have used this regex:

```
pattern="/[+]?[0-9]+\.?[^-]?[0-9]*/";
```

But it accepts *0.-99* .
What is the correct regex to not accept  .-99

Comment: Use `/^[+-]?\d*(?:\.\d+)?$/`

Comment: `-.34` is fine but `.-34` is not

Comment: @anubhava: "But it shouldn't accept negative numbers"

Comment: To disallow negative just remove `-` from `[+-]`

Comment: @anubhava ... the above regex does not recognize `'0.'` which is a valid input value

Comment: It is valid as per OP's requirement or as per mathematical validation?

Comment: @anubhava ... Tee latter, it doesn't validate even though it is valid when written directly as number type or being parsed from a string.

Comment: Ria, is `0.` valid for you here?

Comment: @RiaRajan ... Regarding the provided answers / solutions / approaches are there any questions left?

Comment: @RiaRajan ... At SO it is considered to be a nice gesture from the one who got help, to provide some feedback (don't just disappear) and/or accept the answer which was the most helpful in solving the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/^([.\d][\d]*\.?[\d]+)/g

/         
^       beginning of the input
(       
[.\d]  starting charater of the input should be either a '.', or a digit
[\d]+  then any number of digits after the first character
\.?    matches the decimal '.', ? indicates that it is optional
[\d]+  matches digits after the decimal position
)
/
g      js re global flag
```

Test this regex here: https://regex101.com/r/c5ELUl/1

Comment: The above regex fails for single digits like `'0'` or `'5'`, and it doesn't recognize `'0.'` or `'5.'` either which are bot valid input values. On the other hand it accepts `'0.0.'` or `'0.0.0'` though.

Answer (score 0):

The next provided example code features both, a final validation and an immediate input value sanitizing. Both tasks are regex based.

The former covers the OP's acceptance criteria ... the pattern is as follows ... [`/^(?<=-*)\+?\d*\.?\d+$|^(?<=-*)\+?\d+\.$/`](https://regex101.com/r/ddMyLD/4).

The latter restricts user input while typing continues or copy-paste happens ... the pattern is based on the above, more strict, pure validation ... [`/^(?<=-*)(?<sign>\+?)(?<integer>\d*)(?<point>\.?)(?<float>\d*)/`](https://regex101.com/r/ddMyLD/1).

```js
function isValidNumberValue(value) {
  value = String(value);

  return (
    (value === '') ||
    (/^(?<=-*)\+?\d*\.?\d+$|^(?<=-*)\+?\d+\.$/).test(value)
    // see ... [https://regex101.com/r/ddMyLD/4]

    //(/^(?<=-*)\+?\d*\.?\d+$/).test(value)
    // // see ... [https://regex101.com/r/ddMyLD/2]    
  );
}

function validateNumberValue({ currentTarget }) {
  currentTarget.classList.toggle('invalid', !isValidNumberValue(currentTarget.value));
}
function resetValidation({ currentTarget }) {
  currentTarget.classList.remove('invalid');
}

function sanitizeImmediately({ currentTarget }) {
  let { value } = currentTarget;
  value = value.trim();

  const {
    sign = '', integer = '', point = '', float = ''
  } = (/^(?<=-*)(?<sign>\+?)(?<integer>\d*)(?<point>\.?)(?<float>\d*)/)
    // see ... [https://regex101.com/r/ddMyLD/1]
    .exec(
      currentTarget.value.trim()
    )
    ?.groups ?? {};

  currentTarget.value = [sign, integer, point, float].join('');
}

function init() {
  const control = document.querySelector('[type="text"]');

  control.addEventListener('input', sanitizeImmediately);
  control.addEventListener('focusin', resetValidation);
  control.addEventListener('focusout', validateNumberValue);
}
init();

console.log(
  "isValidNumberValue('') ?..",
  isValidNumberValue('')
);
console.log(
  "isValidNumberValue('  ') ?..",
  isValidNumberValue('  ')
);
console.log(
  "isValidNumberValue('-0') ?..",
  isValidNumberValue('-0')
);
console.log(
  "isValidNumberValue('0') ?..",
  isValidNumberValue('0')
);
console.log(
  "isValidNumberValue(.45) ?..",
  isValidNumberValue(.45)
);
console.log(
  "isValidNumberValue(-.45) ?..",
  isValidNumberValue(-.45)
);
console.log(
  "isValidNumberValue('.-45') ?..",
  isValidNumberValue('.-45')
);
console.log(
  "isValidNumberValue(99.432) ?..",
  isValidNumberValue(99.432)
);
console.log(
  "isValidNumberValue('+9.43') ?..",
  isValidNumberValue('+9.43')
);
console.log(
  "isValidNumberValue('+9.43.45') ?..",
  isValidNumberValue('+9.43.45')
);
console.log(
  "isValidNumberValue('5.') ?..",
  isValidNumberValue('5.')
);
console.log(
  "isValidNumberValue('.') ?..",
  isValidNumberValue('.')
);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
[type="text"].invalid { border-color: #b00; background-color: #fddddd; }
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 88%!important; }
```

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="16" />
```